# Need to use the connection eventType only once with out using cookies or sessions

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and i want my HTML JavaScript code to execute a connection only once.
As of now the scenario is like when ever my code is executed and

```
if(eventType = "ESTABLISHED"){
/*calling another function which will establish the connection and a screen pop occurs which is important*/
}
```

There might be a change that the `eventType`, which could get on "HOLD", when it is on hold and eventually when it comes off of HOLD all steps in the `eventType = "ESTABLISHED"` as processed again which calls the other function and screen is popped(basically calling an external URL, which is needed for processing orders) again and again which should not be the case.

I want to get rid of this multiple screen pops.

> Can some one please let me know if there is any way to to make the
>   screen pop happen only once when the connection is established in the
>   beginning and when it is come off of hold it should just take the
>   existing established connection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found the answer for this just in case if some else is looking for the same.
I had a global variable set to zero, and when ever the call is established i increment the counter, and once the call is terminated i set the variable to zero.
so only when condition count=0 and eventtype = established is true call is actually established.

Comment: This works in Chrome and not in IE, Any reason why it doesn't work in IE ?